# Why doesn't Zsh assign a value to a variable and I have to use eval?

Tags: eval, zsh

I don't understand this behavior in Zsh:

```
~ % i=0
~ % date_input=2021-01-01
~ % sqlday${i}=$(date -j -v+${i}d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "$date_input" +%Y-%m-%d)
zsh: command not found: sqlday0=2021-01-01
~ %
```

Why does it says "command not found?" Why doesn't it assign the variable to 2021-01-01? However, when I use eval:

```
~ % eval sqlday${i}=$(date -j -v+${i}d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "$date_input" +%Y-%m-%d)
~ % echo $sqlday0 
2021-01-01
```

So I suppose I don't understand why Zsh is trying to execute the first statement as a command but the second statement is actually assigns a variable.

Comment: You should be using an array rather than trying to dynamically create variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment to a simple variable has the form

```
NAME=VALUE
```

Parameter expansion occurs inside *VALUE*, not inside *NAME*. It is unnecessary. Why do you want to generate a variable name dynamically, if you have arrays (associative and non-associative).

```
sqlday[$i]=....
```

would work, if you had defined `sqlday` as an array, for instance by

```
typeset -a sqlday
```

**UPDATE** : Explicitly declaring the array is not necessary (though I would consider it good programming practice). Zsh would deduce from the way you are using `sqlday`, that it must be an array.